# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints when UIToolbarContentView is present

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a custom button on top of a datepicker view. When the datepicker is active I get the "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." The error has popped up After I updated to Xcode 11,

This is my code:

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
let flexBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(viewTapped))
toolbar.sizeToFit()
toolbar.setItems([flexBarButton,done], animated: false)
dateInputTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

This is the error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6fe4230 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f85a6d1b8a0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6c2c220 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f85a6d1c0c0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7f85a6d1b8a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6c2e5e0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f85a6d1c0c0.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7f85a6d1b8a0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6c2f920 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(16)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f85a6edf790'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f85a6ed7060 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6c2d690 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f85a6edf790'Done']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f85a6ed7060 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6f11060 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x7f85a6c22b40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == UIView:0x7f85a6ed6cd0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6f25390 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x7f85a6c22b40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f85a6ed7060.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6f256e0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7f85a6ed6cd0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f85a6ed7060]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6c24880 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x7f85a6c22b40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f85a6d1c0c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6c2c9c0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x7f85a6c22b40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f85a6d1c0c0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85a6c2d690 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f85a6edf790'Done']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f85a6ed7060 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Any ideas to fix the error?

Comment: I'm seeing this with a UIToolBar as well.  It seems to be referring to internal constraints the UIToolBar has set on the 1st button, and it seems to be displaying correctly, so I'm ignoring the log warnings for now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my case this was resolved by specifying a valid frame when instantiating the UIToolbar.
`UIToolbar(frame: ..)` instead of just `UIToolbar()`

For example:

`UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: _viewSizeWidth, height: CGFloat(44))))`

where _viewSizeWidth was calculated elsewhere based on the window size.

Comment: I couldn't make it work. What dimensions did you set?

Comment: Thank you, @jk7. After a bit of tweaking for the main view I used  ```UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))))``` and for a textfield in a custom tableview cell I used ```UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))))```.

Comment: Simply using 100 and 100 works too (from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121474#384249)

Comment: This resolved the conflicting constraints for me as well. Here is the Xamarin version of the code: var dismissKeyboard = new UIToolbar (new CGRect (0.0f, 0.0f, this.vwPickerContainer.Frame.Width, 50.0f));

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 5.2**

The constraint error seems to occur when the width of the `UIToolbar` is set to the width of the screen.  The height seems to be irrelevant.

I have silenced the warning by setting a width wide enough to accept the `UIBarButtonItem`(s).  Making the width too small also invokes the error.

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 44.0)))
```

Comment: Can confirm, fixed it for me too.